# Merging [mtm] to [microsoft-test-manager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think [mtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mtm) is as same as [microsoft-test-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-test-manager), so can we merge them?

[[microsoft-test-manager] info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/microsoft-test-manager/info)

[[mtm] info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mtm/info)

Comment: It had a pending synonym request from December and that's been approved now.

Comment: @JonClements thanks ;).